# On text changed in Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, textbox

i need to be able to able to detect when any character is entered into a textbox in Javascript, and clear another corresponding textbox. I have used the onfocus method for this but when tabbing between textboxes to get to submit, it removes the data and I don't want it to.

What methods are there I can use to trigger a JS event when a textbox is entered into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are the following events

[onkeydown](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp)

[onkeyup](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp)

[onkeypress](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp)

Comment: onpaste, oncut, onmouseup (for drag and drop)...

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery:

```
$("#myTextbox").keypress()
$("#myTextbox").keyup()
$("#myTextbox").keydown()
```

and if you want to find out which key was pressed, try:

```
$("#myTextbox").keydown(function(e){ alert(e.which); });
```

if you're not using e.which, you're gonna have cross-browser problems.